# Using beautifulsoup4 in my django app how do I get the "a" href and image src?

Tags: python, html, django, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup4 in my django app to scrape data. I was able to get the data from this html structure

```
   <div class="thumbnail thumb">
        <h6 id="date">May 9, 2016</h6>


        <img src="http://assets.system.jpg" class="img-responsive post">


        <div style="border-bottom: thin solid lightslategray; padding-bottom: 15px;"></div>

        <div class="caption" id="cap">
            <a href="/blog/homeland-security-attack/">
                <h5 class="post-title" id="title">Homeland Security </h5>
            </a>

            <p>
                <a href="/blog/88/delete/" class="btn" role="button">delete</a>
                <a href="/blog/homeland-" class="btn" role="button">edit</a>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>
```

using this in my view

```
url = 'http://www.hispanicheights.com/'
google = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(google.content, 'html.parser')
divs = bs.findAll('div', 'thumbnail')
    entries = [{'text': div.text,
          'href': div.find('a').get('href'),
          'src': div.find('img').get('src')
          } for div in divs][:6]
```

But when I tried to scrape this html structure

```
<div class="entry entry-pos-1" id="entry-217985">
        <a href="/article/murder" data-page="1">
            <p class="entry-comments">6</p>
            <img data-original="/images17985.jpg" alt="Chicago Rapper &amp; OTF Aff Murder" width="320" height="179" class="image-load" src="/images/size_mb/video-217985.jpg" style="display: block;">
        </a>
        <p class="entry-title">
            <a href="/article/-murder" data-page="1">Chicago Rapper &amp; OT Murder</a>
        </p>
        <p class="entry-meta">97 views</p>
        <p class="entry-date">
        <span class="entry-recent">11 Mins Ago</span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

using the same thing

```
ad_url = 'http://www.ad.com/'
ad_get = requests.get(ad_url, headers=headers)
ad_soup = BeautifulSoup(ad_get.content, 'html.parser')
ad_div = vlad_soup.findAll('div', 'entry')
ad_entry = [{'text': div.text,
              'href': div.find('a').get('href'),
              'src': div.find('img').get('src')
                 } for div in ad_div]
```

It get the error Nonetype object has attribute has attribute get

Whats the proper syntax to grab the href and src?

Comment: You use `vlad_div` but don't define it in the code you've pasted here.

Comment: Possibly, some `div` doesn't contain `a` or `img` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `div.find('a')` for a `div` that does not contain an anchor, it will return `None`. Your code has to handle this. For example, you could do:

```
entries = []
for div in vlad_div:
    a = div.find('a')
    img = div.find('img')
    if a is not None and img is not None:
        entry = {
            'text': div.text
            'href': a.get('href')
            'src': img.get('src')
        }
        entries.append(entry)
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly. I have to be able to do it similar to the way my code is so the images href and text all match up. the way you have it it wont work and not only that your way works without me includeing it in my template. It just appears

Comment: The code looks ok to me, but I wouldn't be too surprised if you have to change it slightly. My main point is that you have to check the result of `div.find('a')`. You can't just do `div.find('a').get('href')` because it might throw an error.

Comment: why won't my code work? Can you pinpoint it so I don't keep charging at walls for nothing. this is a bit frustrating because it seems to work arbitrarily

Comment: As I said before, it looks like you are calling `div.find('a').get('href')` on a div that does not contain an anchor. You need to adjust your code in a similar way to what I've done above. I can't help you any more than that. Don't hurt yourself charging at walls ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll do that?